# Ui is updating only for last stream in flutter

Tags: flutter, listview, sms, stream-builder

I am making a sms_app that can get data from the List of Objects when I press the button **send the sms**.Objects have a method which returns a stream. I am iterating through the data with ListViewbuilder and listening to stream via StreamViewBuilder. All the Object Streams are performing the function of sending the message. If i press the first send button ,then wait,press the  second button and wait, it updates the UI accordingly.
But
**UI is being updated for the last Stream. If I press the button one after another button without waiting. What am I doing wrong>**.
Here is the [Video](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1kdbdE_WxamUkGqve6ip-PqN7MUKcJgZS/view?usp=sharing)

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:sms_maintained/sms.dart';

class SendSmsScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  final SmsSender sender = SmsSender();
  final SmsMessage message = SmsMessage('03009640742', '_body');
  final List<SmsMessage> smsList = [
    SmsMessage('03009750742', 'Random'),
    SmsMessage('03008750742', 'Kaleem'),
    SmsMessage('03056750742', 'Shahryar'),
    SmsMessage('03127750742', 'Shahryar Zong')
  ];
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(),
        body: ListView.builder(
          itemCount: smsList.length,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            return SingleChildScrollView(
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  IconButton(
                    icon: Icon(Icons.send),
                    onPressed: () async {
                      await sender.sendSms(smsList[index]);
                    },
                  ),
                  StreamBuilder<SmsMessageState>(
                    key: GlobalKey(debugLabel: 'String $index'),
                    // initialData: SmsMessageState.None,
                    builder: (context, snapshot) {
                      if (snapshot.data == SmsMessageState.Sent) {
                        return Text('Message Sent');
                      }
                      if (snapshot.data == SmsMessageState.Delivered) {
                        return Text('Message Delivered');
                      }
                      if (snapshot.data == SmsMessageState.Sending) {
                        return Text('Sending');
                      }
                      if (snapshot.data == SmsMessageState.Fail)
                        return Text('Sending Failed');
                      return Text('Error');
                    },
                    stream: smsList[index].onStateChanged,
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            );
          },
        ));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming the UI doesn't update properly if pressing the button too quickly.

You can disable the button (example below) until the message is delivered you just need to set your button to be a child of the StreamBuilder.

```
onPressed: snapshot.data == SmsMessageState.Sending ? null : () async {
                  await sender.sendSms(smsList[index]);
                }
```

Comment: The ui is not updating when i pressed list of button like in the video [https://drive.google.com/file/d/1kdbdE_WxamUkGqve6ip-PqN7MUKcJgZS/view?usp=sharing]

Answer (score 0):

That's because they are all executing the same method.  When you do multiple executions in quick succession, last one stops the execution of previous.  You'll have to find a way to queue them as they are executed and only do the next one when when the previous one is finished.

Comment: Can you guide me how can i perform this. I am newbie in flutter